# How can I fix WDIO and Chromedriver slow performance after Chrome update v114?

Tags: webdriver-io

I created a node.js app with chromedriver v111 and Chrome v112 some time ago. Did not run tests since then and currently chromedriver with either v113 or v114 is being executed few times longer.

Also, after update, I started catching wdio errors related to web scraping in random places where page loads take unbelievable time.

Tried to play with chromedriver v110-v114 - either browser continuously opens-closes like in a loop, or execution time is still enormous.

What can be a root cause of such behaviour and is there a chance to fix it somehow? (downgrading Chrome version is not an appropriate solution for now)

related package.json modules:
"chromedriver": "^113.0.0",
"wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.2.8",
"webdriverio": "^7.23.0"

Comment: Same problem, but only on Mac + Chrome. Before chromedriver v113 it was all good. Probably because of this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4456